# GUI using Swing - Trying to get an IF Statement to work with two buttons in the statement

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, if-statement

I'm writing a Slot machine GUI and i want it so that The Slot machine will stop Reel 1 and roll reel 2 and 3 when "Respin" is pressed. This code is not working for me please help:

```
if (event.getSource()== btnHold1)
  {
      counter = 0;   
      timer1.stop();
      btnHold1.setEnabled(false);
  }

  if (event.getSource()== btnHold1 && event.getSource()== btnRespin)
  {
      timer2.start();
      counter2=0;
      timer3.start();
      counter3=0;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The button source cannot be two different buttons. getSource() checks which button was pressed - you are checking if button1 AND button2 were both pressed at the same time. That can never happen.

I suspect you want your second if to be

```
if (event.getSource() == btnRespin)
```

Comment: yes. it's a little hard to explain. i understand that this means both buttons are pressed at the same time which is impossible. however i need the code to state that If btnHold1 is pressed and then btnRespin is pressed, timer1 should stop but timer2 and timer3 should start

Comment: @MichaelG You could test if `btnHold1` is *enabled* in an `else` (since you disable it once it has been clicked). Alternatively, add another state variable.

Comment: @nHouser9 how would i test to see if it was enabled?

Comment: @MichaelG That was my comment. Call [`btnHold1.isEnabled()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isEnabled%28%29)

Comment: @nHouser9 is there a way to see if btnHold1 is not enabled though?
btnHold1.isEnabled() is obviously testing to see if it is enabled?

Comment: @MichaelG Why do you keep replying to nHouser? Use `boolean` negation, `!btnHold1.isEnabled()`

Comment: @MichaelG yeah Elliott's comment for seeing if a button is enabled should be solid.

Answer (score 3):

The condition `event.getSource()== btnHold1 && event.getSource()== btnRespin` isn't possible. If you only have two buttons, just use an `else`.

```
if (event.getSource() == btnHold1) {
    counter = 0;   
    timer1.stop();
    btnHold1.setEnabled(false);
} else {
    timer2.start();
    timer3.start();
    counter3 = counter2 = 0;
}
```

If you have more than two buttons use an `else if` like

```
if (event.getSource() == btnHold1) {
    counter = 0;   
    timer1.stop();
    btnHold1.setEnabled(false);
} else if (event.getSource() == btnRespin) {
    timer2.start();
    timer3.start();
    counter2 = counter3 = 0;
} // else ...
```